# Mysql Query "OR" and "AND"

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-num-rows

```
$assault_checker=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM assaults WHERE host_id='".$_SESSION['user']."' OR guest_id='".$_SESSION['user']."' AND status='0'");
$assault_checker=mysql_num_rows($assault_checker);
```

I keep getting the wrong expected result.
I just want to count the number of rows where the user id is in host_id or guest_id. Also the status row should be 0.

What am I missing?

Comment: Your next stop should be finding out how to protect your program and avoid sql injection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes you should use brackets, your query should be:

```
$assault_checker=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM assaults WHERE (host_id='".$_SESSION['user']."' OR guest_id='".$_SESSION['user']."') AND status='0'");
```

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm

Comment: Here is [documentation on operator precedence](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/operator-precedence.html)